# How to project surface curvature into the domain

Tags: geometry, surfaces, curvature, differential, projection

I have a parameterized surface $h$, defined on an orthogonal (u,v) plane, described by:
$$
h(u,v)=\sqrt{(au+bv+c)^2+(du+ev+f)^2} 
$$
where $a...f$ are parameters. I’m choosing $a...f$ so that the surface is well behaved: smooth, no negative roots or discontinuities. The surface forms a simple valley, and the valley floor seems to be a sloping straight line when I plot the function.

My question is: what is the relationship between $u$ and $v$ describing the valley in the $(u,v)$ plane, i.e. how do I find the valley floor (principal curvature?) and then project it into the $(u,v)$ plane (red line in the plot)?

In other words, if there is just a simple linear relationship between $u$ and $v$ describing the valley floor, i.e. $u(v)=mv+n$, how can I find $m$ and $n$ from the parameters $a…f$? 
[plot of $h(u,v)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cARBs.jpg)

Comment: Perhaps examine the gradient of your height function, $$\nabla h(u,v) = \left ( \frac{\partial h(u,v)}{\partial u} ,\, \frac{\partial h(u,v)}{\partial v} \right ) = \frac{1}{h(u,v)} \left( a ( a u + b v + c) + d ( d u + e v + f ) ,\, b ( a u + b v + c ) + f ( d u + e v + f ) \right)$$, at the valley extremum point where $\nabla h(u,v) = (0, 0)$), $$u = \frac{b f - c e}{a e - b d}, \, \, \, v = \frac{c d - a f}{a e - b d}$$, if one exists ($a e \ne b d$)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Problem is that the gradient, even in the valley is not actually zero (the valley is sloped); what I'd like to find is not a point on the surface where the gradient is zero (or even is minimal), but a line defined by the extreme curvature of the surface. But even if I was to calculate some curvature (H, K, kappa) of the surface (I did), I still end up with a new surface, this time the height representing the original surface's curvature, and I'm back to the problem of finding the line that traces this new surfaces valley (or peak)....

Comment: Well, at the valley floor the gradient is *small*. Find the closed curves in $(u, v)$, where $\left\lVert\nabla h(u, v) \right\rVert = \epsilon$. If the gradient points "inside" the curve on the closed curve, that curve is the perimeter of the valley. (If the gradient points "outside" the curve, that curve is the perimeter of a plateau instead.)

Comment: If you really expect a valley floor (i.e., a straight line forming the trough of the surface), the Gaussian curvature will need to be $0$ along these points, and I am pretty sure that will only happen if the two linear forms $au+bv$ and $du+ev$ are scalar multiples of one another along that locus.

Comment: I should have specified more clearly that the _projection_ of the valley seems to be a straight line (when viewn 'from above'); it might be curve up or down. How would that case be treated?